Error when using mcode.sty package - Inserts "2D at first page
When using the mcode.sty package to include code from Matlab,
and compile it with pdflatex I am experiencing the error as follow,
(same error with TeXstudio and Overleaf):
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.297 ...ocessOther {"2D}{\lst@ttfamily{-{}}{-{}}}
                                                  
A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)

! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.
<to be read again> 
                   \protect 
l.297 ...ocessOther {"2D}{\lst@ttfamily{-{}}{-{}}}
                                                  
I was expecting to see `<', `=', or `>'. Didn't.

When commenting the following code snippet in mcode.sty the error vanishes:
% fix for ``minus'' character issue, as suggested by Stefan Karlsson, thanks!
\makeatletter 
\lst@CCPutMacro\lst@ProcessOther {"2D}{\lst@ttfamily{-{}}{-{}}} 
\@empty\z@\@empty 
\makeatother

What can be the reason for it? Does anybody else experience this?
Testing code for Overleaf:
% !TeX program = txs:///pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{ngerman}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{float}
 %LaTeX with packages "listings", "xcolor" and "textcomp".
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage[framed]{mcode} 

\begin{document}
\section{singleline}
Hello world
\begin{lstlisting}
test - testing
\end{lstlisting}
\mcode{for}
\mcode{asdf-3}
\subsection{multiline}
\begin{lstlisting}
%%%Fibers
%Fraction
f_glas=0.6; %[-]
%K-Modulus
K_glas=41.6; %[GPa]
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}

Edit:
Changing \usepackage{ngerman} to \usepackage[ngerman]{babel} seems to make it work.

Welcome to TeX.SE. Please post MWE in a workable format, i.e., from \documentclass to \end{document} as always

I would guess in code not shown you have enabled a babel language that defines " as an active character for babel shorthands.

change "2D to 45 and it'll probably work.

Changing "2D to 45 does work. Would you be able to explain the reason? Thank you!

ngerman is an obsolete package, use the ngerman option to babel instead. also don't use utf8x it would break latex except that it is trapped with a warning and does nothing.

Never use
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

it does nothing other than issue a warning
Package ucs Info: utf8x disabled, assuming standard utf8 processing
(ucs)             load ucs package to force utf8x processing.

Similarly the ngerman package is a very old legacy package that defines " to be active for shorthands for constructs such as "o for o-umlaut.
Instead use
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

which has been the standard interface since latex2e was introduced in 1993, and delays the defintion so " has its normal meaning with catcode 12, until \begin{document} to avoid breaking other packages.
"2D is primitive TeX syntax for a hexadecimal number so 2*16+13=45 so replacing it by 45 also works but fixing the document not to use these legacy interfaces is better.
I don't have mcode package as it is not in texlive, so no sample output.

Thank you very much for this explanation!
Indeed the original document is a developing document with sections written in former decades.
